# ActiveMQ bridging messages to Solace

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, solace

Is there any way I can bridge messages sent to a topic on ActiveMQ 5.14.3 to a topic on Solace 10.0.1.41?

I checked ActiveMQ documentation and it supports JMS as does Solace. However, I have no idea how I could bridge the messages. I prefer just configuration setup instead of having another standalone service to host.

If any other protocol can do the same case (bridging messages from ActiveMQ to Solace) please also let me know so I can try it out as well!

P.S. I am still a newbie to both ActiveMQ and Solace. If a working example could be provided it would be a great help to me.

Comment: Your best bet is likely Camel since both ActiveMQ and Solace provide a JMS client implementation.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks, but does it mean I need to keep running a Java application in order to keep the bridge alive?

Comment: No. The bridge can be deployed directly in the ActiveMQ configuration.

Comment: @JustinBertram That would be great, could you please advise is there any documentation or tutorial I can follow or reference?

Comment: Try this - https://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.

Comment: How about sending topic from solace to activemq?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ has 'JMS connector' support for point-to-point bridges. Camel routes can also be added and run in-broker as mentioned by @justin in the comments.